# How to hide/disable the checkbox of a free(price = 0) downloadable product?

Tags: downloadable

How can I disable or hide a downloadable file checkbox(basically making it unselectable)with a price of 0? I'm create a music store, Im using a downloadable product type to create an album. I would like to make some songs not be able to be sold separately but show them as the part of the album.

Magento 1.7

Please see my screenshot, the last song shouldn't be selectable. Thanks
[screenshot](http://beatscent.com/websites/misc/album3.PNG)[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the template where the files are listed, check the price and if the price is zero don't show it ;-)

I think it is here:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/catalog/product/links.phtml
```

Just check the price in line 37 `$_link->getPrice() == 0` and if it is zero, don't show the `<li>`

Comment: Thank you so much, I wanted to only hide the checkbox not the whole <li> but I managed to accomplish it with your guidance. I changed line 38 a bit.Thank You again :-)

<?php if ($_linksPurchasedSeparately && $_link->getPrice() != 0): ?>

Comment: Im not sure if you can also help me with this related question as well if you can :-)  [Disable other checkboxes...](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10080/how-can-i-disable-other-downloadable-products-checkboxes)