# How can I disable other downloadable products checkboxes?

Tags: downloadable

I have a music album as a downloadable product type, which lists all songs and the whole album as zipped. So the customer can buy individual songs or just select the whole album. I want to disable individual songs if the customer selects the full album, Like in this music store when you click on "Entire Release" [JunoDownload](http://www.junodownload.com/products/sven-weisemann-inner-motions/2290949-02/)

Please see my screenshot for what I have at the moment. [Screenshot](http://beatscent.com/websites/misc/album2.PNG)

Comment: Use javascript to disable other checkboxes once you select the checkbox for the entire album.

Comment: @Shatir Thanks, On which file? what would the JavaScript look like? I have hardly used JS, I'm still new to Magento, this is my first attempt, Any help would be appreciated :-) Thanks

Comment: I haven't worked with downloadable products yet. But you'd have to add the javascript in the phtml file which displays those options.
If you don't know the file, just switch on template path hints from **System->Configuration** then on left menu bar goto **Developer** then in **Debug** you can set **template path hints** to yes. (Note you'd have to select **Current Configuration Scope** before you can see the path hints option)

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to write the JS into the options phtml file.

You want to add a js file to the layout handle: `PRODUCT_TYPE_downloadable`.
[On stackoverflow is described how to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3938134/1480397)

And then you have to check how the checkboxes are named and abstract some regex or something (I have no idea how this would look like).

And then you write something like:

```
$('album_checkbox_find_abstract_name').observer('changed', function(event){
    if(this.checked) {
        $$('.some_class_around_all_the_checkboxes input[type=checkbox]').each(function(elem) {
            if(elem != this) elem.disabled = true;
        });
    } else {
        $$('.some_class_around_all_the_checkboxes input[type=checkbox]').each(function(elem) {
            elem.disabled = false;
        });
    }
});
```

Hope this helps. No time for testing. Maybe you have a wrong this inside the each functions.

Comment: +1 Nice! Its a more appropriate way go about it (Magento style)... Get to learn new things every now & then from stackexchange. :)